# Select Item option value returns NULL

Tags: javascript, c#, .net-core, model-view-controller, entity-framework-core

I am listing the cities of the selected country and districts of the selected city in select list item in my view as :

```
<select class="form-control mb-2" id="countrySelect">
      <option value="">--Choose a country--</option>
      @foreach (CountryDto country in ViewBag.Countries)
      {
          <option value="@country.Id">@country.Name</option>
      }
</select>
<select class="form-control mb-2" id="citySelect"></select>
<select class="form-control mb-2" id="@nameof(Model.DistrictId)"></select>
```

The cities and districts are coming from javascript code as :

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    
        $('#countrySelect').change(function (event) {
            var countryId = $(this).val();
            LoadCities(countryId);
        });
    
        $('#citySelect').change(function (event) {
            var cityId = $(this).val();
            LoadDistricts(cityId);
        });
    
        $('#DistrictId').change(function (event) {
            var disctId = $(this).val();
            $('input[name="districtId"]').val(disctId);
        });
    });
    
    function LoadCities(countryId) {
        // For City
        $.ajax({
            url: `/Customer/GetCities?countryId=${countryId}`,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                
                for (var city of data) {
                    $('#citySelect').append(`<option value="${city.id}">${city.cityName}</option>`);
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                
            },
            complete: function () {
                
            }
        });
    }

function LoadDistricts(cityId) {
    // For District
    $.ajax({
        url: `/Customer/GetDistricts?cityId=${cityId}`,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            for (var district of data) {
                $('#DistrictId').append(`<option value="${district.id}">${district.districtName}</option>`)
            }
            
        },
        error: function () {
            
        },
        complete: function () {
            
        }
    });
}
```

In Customer Controller : Get and AddOrUpdate Methods

```
[HttpGet("Customer/{id}")] 
        public IActionResult Get(int id)
        {
            var customer = _customerServices.GetCustomer(id) ?? new CustomerDto();
            ViewBag.Countries = _customerServices.GetCountries();
            ViewBag.Sectors = _customerServices.GetSectors();
            return View(customer);
        }

        [HttpPost("Customer/AddOrUpdate")] 
        public IActionResult AddOrUpdate(CustomerDto customer)
        {
            _customerServices.AddOrUpdate(customer);
            return View($"Customer");
        }
```

In CustomerServices I wrote this methods:

```
public List<CityDto> GetCities(int countryId)
        {
            var cities = Context.Cities.Where(w => w.CountryId == countryId).ToList();
            return cities.ToMapList<City, CityDto>();
        }

        public List<DistrictDto> GetDistricts(int cityId)
        {
            var districts = Context.Districts.Where(w => w.CityId == cityId).ToList();
            return districts.ToMapList<District, DistrictDto>();
        }

        public List<CountryDto> GetCountries()
        {
            var countries = Context.Countries.ToList();
            return countries.ToMapList<Country, CountryDto>();
        }
```

When attempting to add a new customer CustomerDto is getting all information except districtid coming from the district select item
Value is coming NULL

Would you mind please help ?

Comment: You need to see if your "missing" property-value is in your Orm-Entity BEFORE the "Mapping" to the Dto.  Sometimes you "lose" property-hydration on the mapping ("ToMapList") call.     put a breakpoint on all lines that have "ToMapList" and look at the Orm-Entities before they are converted to Dto's.  #sanityCheck

Comment: It worked now ! I did not understand how I did not changed anything ..... But now there is one more problem when the user changes cities in dropdown, the districts related to that city remains in the district dropdown how will I clear the old ones ?